# Is $f(X)=-tr(AXBX^T)$ convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Given $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and they are non-negative matrix.

Is $f(X)=-tr(AXBX^T)$ convex when $X$ is also non-negative?

If yes, how can I show that?

Comment: Is there any condition on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Raskolnikov No, just squared real matrices

Comment: Well, suppose for some choice of $A$ and $B$, your function is convex, then change $B$ with $-B$ and your function is concave.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thanks for pointing this out. I think I have to add one more thing: $A$ and $B$ are non-negative.

Comment: Then the answer is trivially "no" since when $N=1$, one is looking at the function $f:x\mapsto-abx^2$, which is concave when $ab\gt0$.

Comment: This seems to have some relation with Lieb's concavity theorem. See the Wikipedia article on trace inequalites: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities. But do you really have a minus sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applied to matrices (instead of operators), "nonnegative" usually means entrywise nonnegative. I am not sure if you are considering nonnegative matrices or positive semidefinite matrices, but the answer is "no" in both cases.

If $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative, the answer is no in general. For examples, when $A=B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ and $X=\pmatrix{x&z\\ y&w}$, $-\mathrm{trace}(AXBX^T)=-2(wx+yz)$ is neither convex nor concave: put $w=x=0$ and observe that $yz$ is not midpoint concave if we consider $y=z$, and it is not midpoint convex if we consider $(y_1,z_1)=(1,3)$ and $(y_2,z_2)=(3,1)$. Note that the $X$ in this counterexample is nonnegative too.

If $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, then
$$
-\mathrm{trace}(AXBX^T)=-\mathrm{trace}(A^{1/2}XB^{1/2}B^{1/2}X^TA^{1/2})=-\mathrm{trace}\left((A^{1/2}XB^{1/2})(A^{1/2}XB^{1/2})^T\right),
$$
which is a *concave* function of $X$. Again, this is not convex in general.